# Dialog asking if user wants to allow use of location services pops and disappears in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-location

My iPhone application uses location services. When i first install and run it, it shows dialog asking if user wants to allow use of location services for a moment and immediately disappears. This happens few times in a row.

Is it a known bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you post some of the code that uses the Location Manager?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same issue in my app just now, I'll add this as an answer for anyone who googles the question and comes across this old question.

The problem is that if you instanciate CLLocationManager locally and ask it to update its location, the window which asks for permission disappears instantly after it pops up.

You have to make CLLocationManager a property (or at least you should not instanciate it locally), then it works.

Comment: You're right: that is because the local variable is not referenced anywhere else and so ARC will release it and it will get deallocated, causing the dialog to disappear.
So make the CLLocationManager a property or an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the OS asking you to approve use of location services for the app. I am not aware of any outstanding issues that would prevent that from closing and reopening the way you describe. As far as I know, you don't have any control over this, it will apprear automatically when your app triggers a location based method (e.g. -startUpdatingLocation or -startMonitoringForRegion).

It is possible you have another conflicting view that is trying to steal the view from the OS alert, but without any code, would be hard to say. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep thats exactly what happens. The problem is that i do have different views in which i use location services, but none of them run on application load. The main and first view that loads does not use location services.

Comment: I would think about disabling your location stuff in each spot, and work on adding them back in one at a time until you track down who is giving you trouble. You can reset your Simulator to factory settings and will reset your location services trigger for the app. That should help you test it out.